# StreamWriter from Process hangs on WriteLine();

Tags: c#, process, streamwriter, flush

I have made a piece of software that requires big amounts of communication between 3 processes. However, at some point the WriteLine(string) method from Process.StandardInput just hangs the program.

Here is the codesnippet, it is called MANY times

```
public void Talk(string message)
{
    if (!started)
        Start();
    LogConsole.Log("-> " + this.Name + ": " + message, LogMode.GameLog);

    this.process.StandardInput.WriteLine(message.ToCharArray(), 0, message.Length);
}
```

Comment: How sure are you that the receiving process is draining its input? Maybe it has halted/deadlocked.

Comment: Thank you so much, hadn't even thought about that, if you make it an answer I will choose it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you redirect standard I/O of a process, you have to make sure you're actually reading the input at all times. There's limited buffers in play, so if one of the processes stops reading its inputs, *writing* to it from another process will block until the buffers are emptied / read.

The easiest way to handle this properly is to always use asynchronous I/O to handle reading and writing standard input / output / error. Unless this happens asynchronousy, it's very easy to cause a deadlock between two processes, for example (e.g. one process tries to write while the other one also tries to write and they don't get to the point where they'd actually *read* the data so they're both stuck while writing, because the buffers are full).

Also, don't `Flush`. It's rarely a good idea.

Comment: The sad thing is, I can't do it async. I need turn based communication with a system I will not code. Is there a way to see how full that buffer is?

Comment: @user3018710 That doesn't matter - handle the reading and writing asynchronously, then put the data into a queue or something as appropriate for handling the synchronous communication, handle the buffering yourself if necessary. The limits are actually rather low, I think it's somewhere in the 1-4 kiB realm or so, IIRC (but I really am not sure).

Comment: I might considder that later, but do you know of any way to find out how full that buffer is? I have to terminate the process that does not read anyway.

Comment: @user3018710 That might be quite tricky, I don't think it's quite possible. Instead, you might want to simply use an asynchronous write with a timeout. A simplified example might look like `await Task.WhenAny(new Process().StandardInput.WriteAsync("Test"), Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));`.